# Swift -- address of Array elements

Tags: arrays, swift

I wrote some short codes on [IBM Swift Sandbox](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/) and met a confusing problem

**I tried to get addresses of array elements:**

```
func printMemory(ptr: UnsafePointer<Int>){
    print("At memory:\(ptr)")
}

var arr: [[Int]] = [
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1,2],
    [0]
]
printMemory(&arr[0][0])
printMemory(&arr[1][0])
```

And the output of this code has same addresses.
By changing "UnsafePointer" to "UnsafeMutablePointer" would solve this problem, but I just don't know why this happen.
Why I get the same address at first and what occupies that address?

**Another problem I met:**

Also, if I only change the last two lines of code to:

```
printMemory(&arr[0])
printMemory(&arr[0][1])
```

The compile will pass.
I predict that I would get an error that says arr[0] is of [Int] type does not match Int type in UnsafePointer. But there's no warning.
Also, the two address are far away from each other. I can't explain why.
By using "UnsafeMutablePointer" in printMemory() would get closer addresses.
I think I need an explanation of why this compile would pass and why address act like this.

Sorry for my bad English grammar and thanks for every reply!

Comment: FWIW, I don't see that behavior using `swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu14.04.tar.gz` on Linux; it prints two distinct addresses.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, in an Xcode 7.3 playground I'm seeing different memory locations: `At memory:0x00007fff50d86070` `At memory:0x00007fff50d86058`

Comment: I can reproduce this with Xcode 7.3 in a compiled project. I *assume* that the value is copied to the same memory location because it cannot be modified from the function.

Comment: Maybe this question is partly a small bug on this website? I tried this short code on another website and get another result.
So, the first code should receive different address?

Answer (score -1):

To answer your first question:
Most likely, the compiler realized the common elements shared among those arrays, and made only one array in memory, `[0,1,2,3,4]`, and two slices to act as `[0,1,2]` and `[0]` without actually needing to keep them redundantly in memory.

Comment: You could test that by changing the assigned values so they're all unique.

Comment: That's... interesting.